# Upload GitHub user avatar programmatically?

Tags: api, github, upload, avatar

Do you know if it's possible at all, and if possible - what's the HTTP API or Java API to upload a new avatar?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need an API on GitHub side: as I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10221585/6309), all you need is for your GitHub account email to match the one used for your Gravatar.

That leaves you with a [Gravatar](https://en.gravatar.com/) API call, like [an xmlrpc](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/xmlrpc/): see an [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26099199/6309).

It uses specifically:

```
grav.saveData - Save binary image data as a userimage for this account 
    @param  (string)$args['data'] a base64_encode()d image
    @param  (int)$args['rating'] 0:g, 1:pg, 2:r, 3:x
    @param  (string)$args['password'] for authentication 
    @return (bool)false on failure, (string)userimage on success
```

Answer (score -2):

Thanks, it answered my question

I am personally developing an Android application that uses GitHub SDK and wanted the device to take a picture to replace the avatar, I noticed gravatar API has a Java implentation, I might take that approach, I am a bit afraid because gravatar requires the user password as a raw string (text)